# C - Why are first few elements distorted when I read a matrix from file?

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

I am quite new to C programming and I wish to read a matrix from given file, in the file, elements are space separated.
I tried with the following code, note that it compiled swiftly, but when I examine the content in my matrix, the first 2 elements in each row is distorted to -2145378576 22099:

```
typedef struct matrix {
  int nrow;
  int ncol;
  int** data;
} matrix;

matrix* mread(char* filename) {
  FILE* f = fopen(filename, "r");
  char line[256];

  matrix* result = malloc(sizeof(matrix));
  int** data = malloc(0);
  int ncol, nrow = 0;

  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f)) {
    char* token = strtok(line, " ");
    int* temp = malloc(sizeof(int));
    ncol = 0;
    while (token != NULL) {
      temp = realloc(temp, ++ncol * sizeof(int));
      temp[ncol - 1] = strtol(token, NULL, 10);
      token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    data = realloc(data, ++nrow * sizeof(temp));
    data[nrow - 1] = temp;
    free(temp);
  }
  result->ncol = ncol;
  result->nrow = nrow;
  result->data = data;
  free(data);
  fclose(f);
  return result;
}
```

Now that I tried to read the matrix from project Euler #11, I find that the first 2 elements in each row is distorted. However, I cannot figure out where the problem is (I know it is somewhere around the `realloc` for `data`...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `result->data = data; free(data);` here you are assigning `data` pointer to `result->data` and then freeing the `data`. You will have undefined behavior if your program is accessing `result->data` after this.

Comment: `data[now - 1]`, in this statement, I believe there is a typo. `now` should be `nrow`.

Comment: Is it the same problem when I `data[nrow - 1] = temp; free(temp);`? I meant to use `temp` and `data` as a vehicle for transporting data, so intuitively I free the memory when it's done. How can I achieve that if I cannot free them? Thank you very much!

Comment: _I free the memory when it's done_, no you are not done with the memory pointed by `temp` and `data`. `temp `memory assigned to `nrow` of `data` and further the `data` is assigned to `result->data` and returning `result` from the function.

Comment: Thank you @H.S.! now I free the memories only when destructing the matrix, and it works fine now!

Comment: Note: there is no need to call `strtok`, simply use `strtol` making use of the `endptr` parameter to advance to one character beyond the end of the number read, and allow it to handle consuming any intervening whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is having undefined behavior because you are freeing the pointer after assigning it to the `result` structure member variable `data` and later returning `result` from the function `mread()` *[assuming you must be accessing the `result->data` returned by `mread()`]* :

```
    data[nrow - 1] = temp;
    free(temp);
....
....
result->data = data;
free(data);
```

You should not `free` the `temp` and `data` here. They should be freed when you are done with the `result` pointer returned by `mread()`. Make sure to first free all the `nrow` of `data` and then free the `data`.

Also, you don't need to allocate `malloc(0)` to `data`. Instead, assign `NULL` to `data`. The `realloc` behavior is the same as calling `malloc(new_size)` when the pointer passed to it is `NULL`.